# React tile component only opens link after middle mouse click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make individual tiles to display my portfolio projects. But the strange thing is i can only click on the link with middle mouse click, not left-click. Any thoughts?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Porfolio extends Component {
  render() {
    let resumeData = this.props.resumeData;
    return (
      <section id="portfolio">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="twelve columns collapsed">
          <h1>Check Out Some of My Works.</h1>
          <div id="portfolio-wrapper" className="bgrid-quarters s-bgrid-thirds cf">
          {
            resumeData.portfolio && resumeData.portfolio.map((item)=>{
              return(
                <div className="columns portfolio-item">
                  <div className="item-wrap">
                    <a href={item.url}>
                      <img src={`${item.imgurl}`} className="item-img"/>
                      <div className="overlay">
                        <a href={item.url}>
                        <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
                          <h5>{item.name}</h5>
                          <p>{item.description}</p>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not enough information and code to get a clear picture of what's happening. Could you share more code or the component context (external events and interactions)?

Comment: sure i have added the entire component for context, is there anything else you would like to see?

Comment: Why do you have an <a> tag nested inside another <a> tag? Bound to go weird!

Comment: it wasnt working ealier so I thought the overlay was covering it up, evidently not. I will take it out. But it still doesnt work without the a tag.

Comment: https://www.jackpeng.me/ here is my site if you want to poke at it

Comment: Take a look in your console - there's a javascript error when you click the link.

Comment: I see, it seems like a jquery error. However, I dont recognize any of the files in the trace. I am not good at jquery either, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

hi  if  you talking about the Modal not showing up  you should select the `img` not `a` element

`$('.item-wrap')` instead of `$('.item-wrap a')`

i added option to make it close when clicked

```
$('.item-wrap').magnificPopup({

   type:'inline',
   fixedContentPos: false,closeOnContentClick: true,
   removalDelay: 200,
   showCloseBtn: false,
   mainClass: 'mfp-fade'

});
```

and if you dont wan't to show some thing inside the popup & you want to open new page leading to the github repository you should remove that event listener who overwrites the a link element on click event  because it contains the img and a element

you can remove the  magnific popup call

or change the jq selector to img element not the div element who contains the link

or you can make `<a>inside here the div with class .item-wrap</a>`
i hope this help's